# What is liquibase "Context" analog in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js, liquibase

Can I have some `js` files with migrations which run only for test or local environment? Does sequelize support this? Here is liquibase [analog](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/contexts.html)

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Comment: Both `sequelize` and `liquibase` work with db and generates/apply sql statements, no?